Simplest and smallest of non-powered USB hubs
Situation: Laptop with a USB 3.2 Type A port.  The port has a tiny USB 2.x Type A device always plugged into it.  That device uses very little power (I can measure it, if needed) and does not use much of the USB port's bandwidth.  I would also like to attach a pair of USB speakers to that same USB port.
Is there a tiny non-powered USB hub that will accomplish this goal?

Assuming the speakers are also USB 2 or less, I would just find a low price USB 2 hub on amazon/microcenter/monoprice/adafruit/... or a local store and use that.  I would expect to pay less than $10, possibly less than $5.

I wasn't able to find any specs/documentation for the speakers.  Have you ever heard of USB speakers using more than USB 2?

If it presents as a sound card, I think it could be a full speed (USB 1.1) device.  If it uses a type C connector (USB 3+), it could be attached to the sound channel of the video output.

Those are useful tips.  Thanks.
